# How to programmatically remove content from Xamarin.Forms ScrollView?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

On a content page I have a `scrollview` into which from code-behind I add a grid and content to the grid. I want to remove the previously added content on tap of a button and add new content.

```
<ScrollView Grid.Row="3" x:Name="frequencyView">
</ScrollView>
```

In code behind I have

```
var grid = new Grid();
grid.Rowdefinitions.Add(...)
grid.Children.Add(.. another view..)
frequencyView.Content = grid;
```

However even if I run

`grid.children.clear()` the previously added content is not removed from the view. I have tried `Page.ForceLayout()` and `frequencyView.ForceLayout()` after removing the children from the grid. Setting `frequencyView.Content = null` has no effect.

How do I remove previously added content from the scrollview?

Comment: are you making these changes on the UI thread?

Comment: @Jason Even that doesnt seem to help. I have updated code to use `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` No dice :-(

Comment: Try Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread insted of MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread

Comment: Can you share more code or a basic sample which can reproduce this problem? I tried `grid.children.clear()` and the `children` did remove on my side.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT To each grid row, I add a Syncfusion chart control. On the tap of a button, I reload the chart data and am trying to remove previously added chart and replace with new chart. Are you saying UI screen elements are removed for you?

Comment: Yes, I added some labels in the grid and removed them successfully. It should be same when add/remove charts.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you should not remove UI objects from your layout. You should create your layout then hide / show controls...